# Auto-hide tabs bar in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext

does someone know how I can get Sublime Text 2 to auto-hide the tabs bar when onyl one file is opened?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [little auto-hide tabs extension](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1357) for doing exactly that. If you wait, something like this should probably get added to ST2.

Comment: you know how to install this python script?